# extract specific word from comma separated string in java using regex

Tags: java, regex

input - `[1, 1111, 2020, BMW, Frontier, EXTENDED CAB PICKUP 2-DR, Silver, 16558]`
I want to extract here BMW and I am using `(^(?:[^\\,]*\\,){3})` this regex. 
This results into -  `BMW, Frontier, EXTENDED CAB PICKUP 2-DR, Silver, 16558]`. 
Could any one help me with this? thanks in advance

Comment: You could split on a comma followed by a space or use a capturing group  `\[(?:[^,]+,){3}\h*([^,]+)` https://regex101.com/r/AR6iXX/1

Comment: Why not `str.substring(1, str.length() - 1).split(", ")[3]`

Comment: Check https://ideone.com/Avwz76

Comment: Thanks for the response. There is a function already written ..in that I have to pass regex and input string...that function will return first capturing group. And here https://regex101.com/r/AR6iXX/1 the result is in group1.

Comment: If you match the rest of the string until the closing `]` you could replace with group 1 and get only BMW `\[(?:[^,]+,){3}\h*([^,]+)[^\]\[]*\]` See https://regex101.com/r/iITH74/1

Comment: Did the previous pattern not work? If you want to match the trailing , as well and 3-10 word chars `\[(?:[^,]+,){3}\h*(\w{3,10},)[^\]\[]*\]` https://regex101.com/r/HjrU4I/1

Comment: No... this returns full match string- `[1, 1111, 2020, BMW, Frontier, EXTENDED CAB PICKUP 2-DR, Silver, 16558] ` not 'BMW'

Comment: The result is in the first capturing group. You wrote in the previous comment `There is a function already written ..in that I have to pass regex and input string...that function will return first capturing group.` In Java you have to double escape the backslashes `String regex = "\\[(?:[^,]+,){3}\\h*(\\w{3,10},)[^\\]\\[]*\\]";`

Comment: My mistake.. its returning the full match not a group

Comment: You could specify a finite quantifier in the lookbehind and repeat that part 3 times https://ideone.com/idF1Xk

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you can only enter a pattern without making use of groups, you could make use of finite repetition for example `{0,1000}` in the positive lookbehind as Java does not support infinite repetition.

```
(?<=^\\[[^,]{0,1000},[^,]{0,1000},[^,]{0,1000},\\h{0,10})\\w{3,10}(?=[^\\]\\[]*\\])
```

*Explanation*

- `(?<=` Positive lookbehind, assert what is on the left is

  - `^\[` Start of string, match `[`
  - `[^,]{0,1000},[^,]{0,1000},[^,]{0,1000},` Match 3 times any char except `,` followed by the `,`
  - `\h{0,10}` Match 0-10 times a horizontal whitespace char
- `)` Close lookbehind
- `\w{3,10}` Match 3-10 word chars
- `(?=` Positive lookahead, assert what is on the right is

  - `[^\]\[]*\]` Match until the `]`
- `)` Close lookahead

[Java demo](https://rextester.com/NQL31802)

*Code example*

```
final String regex = "(?<=^\\[[^,]{0,1000},[^,]{0,1000},[^,]{0,1000},\\h{0,10})\\w{3,10}(?=[^\\]\\[]*\\])";
final String string = "[1, 1111, 2020, BMW, Frontier, EXTENDED CAB PICKUP 2-DR, Silver, 16558]";

final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

while (matcher.find()) {
    System.out.println(matcher.group(0));
}
```

*Output*

```
BMW
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is comma seperated string, you could just split function from the string class which would convert the comma seperated string to array. Refer - [Link](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/split-string-java-examples/)

> The string split() method breaks a given string around matches of the
>   given regular expression.

**Syntax - Public String [ ] split ( String regex, int limit )**

```
Input String: 016-78967
Regular Expression: -
Output : {"016", "78967"}
```

Then you could into the array to find out the particular keyword from it.

Comment: Or if you are so fascinated by the regex you could do this too -https://regex101.com/r/Y1D6dr/1
Just fetch out the group1 match and you would get BMW

Comment: the regex is working properly with the current input but I want to make it dynamic. In this I want to extract the 4th word(i.e. after 4th , sign) with any no. of character.